# Base64.decode(privateKeyString, Base64.DEFAULT) in Commons Codec

Tags: java, apache-commons-codec

Using Android's `Base64`, it's possible to do this: `Base64.decode(privateKeyString, Base64.DEFAULT)`. If you are using Apache's Commons Codec, this isn't available. How can I achieve the same result using Commons Codec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javadoc for Apache Commons Codec `Base64` class can be found here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html

For your case, you need to use `Base64.decodeBase64(String base64String)` method

Comment: I know that Android's 'Base64.DEFAULT' causes operation to use line terminators. Does 'Base64.decodeBase64(String base64String)' use line terminators as well?

Comment: Line terminators make sense on encoding data to base64. If you want your base64 encoded string to be divided on standard 76 characters chunks - use method `encodeBase64(byte[] binaryData, boolean isChunked)` with `isChunked=true`. However, line terminators don't impact on decoding, they're simply ignored.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We have been worrying if line terminators would affect decoding since we are using two encoding libraries on the server and client side. Now we can let our worries go and focus our efforts on functional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

delete the base64 string head.for example,"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0....",delete the string "data:image/png;base64,".then.it work well. i did it